# Variable 'temp1Ord' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

Tags: c++, function, lambda, linked-list, c++17

In the doppioniInUnaLista function, in the first "if" statement that you see I get this error, Variable 'temp1Ord' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified, and I have no idea on how to fix it, also because it's the first time I use Lambdas in C++. I tried adding an & in the [] brackets, however I still can't figure out how to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Numero {
    int numero;
    Numero* next;
};

template <typename T>
void ForEachLista(T *lista, void (*func)(T* temp));
Numero* createHeadAndAddSpesaToTail();
Numero* addSpesaTail(Numero *numero, int num);
Numero* doppioniInUnaLista(Numero *primo);

int main() {
    
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    
    Numero *lista1 = createHeadAndAddSpesaToTail();
    
    cout << endl;
    
    ForEachLista<Numero>(lista1, [](Numero* temp){
        cout << "Numero: " << temp -> numero << endl;
    });

    cout << endl;
    
    Numero* doubles = doppioniInUnaLista(lista1);

    cout << endl;

    ForEachLista<Numero>(doubles, [](Numero* temp){
        cout << "Numero: " << temp -> numero << endl;
    });
    
    
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void ForEachLista(T *lista, void (*func)(T* temp)){
    T* temp = lista;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        func(temp);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}


Numero* createHeadAndAddSpesaToTail(){
    string stop {"x"};
    Numero *oggetto = new Numero;
    
    oggetto -> numero = rand() % 10;
    oggetto -> next = nullptr;
    
    Numero *temp = new Numero;
    temp = oggetto; //temp è uguale a oggetto che in questo fino a questo momento è la testa della lista
    do{
        cout << "Oggetto è stato aggiunto, vuoi inserirne un'altro, se no premi x" << endl;
        cin >> stop;
        
        if (stop != "x"){
            Numero* newOggetto = addSpesaTail(temp, rand() % 10);
            temp = newOggetto; // temp è uguale a newOggetto cosí il prossimo giro non parte da oggetto ma da newOggetto
        }
        
    } while (stop != "x");
    
    return (oggetto); //Se ha scelto head, temp adesso è il primo
}

Numero* addSpesaTail(Numero *spesa, int num){
    Numero *nuovo = new Numero;
    
    nuovo -> numero = num;
    nuovo -> next = nullptr;
    
    spesa -> next = nuovo; //Collego la spesa precedente a quello nuovo
    
    return nuovo;
}

Numero* doppioniInUnaLista(Numero *primo){
    //MARK: SROT
    
    ForEachLista<Numero>(primo, [](Numero* temp1Ord){
        ForEachLista<Numero>(temp1Ord -> next, [](Numero* temp2Ord){
            if (temp1Ord -> numero > temp2Ord -> numero) {
                int temp = temp1Ord -> numero;
                temp1Ord -> numero = temp2Ord -> numero;
                temp2Ord -> numero = temp;
            }
        });
    });

    Numero* headOfNewLista = new Numero;
    
    int numeroRipetuto = -1;
    Numero* tempNewOggetto = headOfNewLista;
    
    //MARK: CREATING NEW LIST IF DOBULE VALUES ARE FOUND, UNIQUELY
    
    Numero* i = primo;
    while (i != nullptr) {
        Numero* j = i -> next;
        while (j != nullptr) {
            if (i -> numero == j -> numero && numeroRipetuto != i -> numero) {
                Numero* newOggetto = addSpesaTail(tempNewOggetto, i -> numero);
                tempNewOggetto = newOggetto;
                numeroRipetuto = i -> numero;
            }
            j = j -> next;
        }
        i = i -> next;
    }

    return headOfNewLista -> next;
}
```

Comment: As the error message says you aren't capturing the variable in the lambda. Adding `&` to the capture group is one way to do it. What errors did you get when you tried?

Comment: I got 'No matching function for call to 'ForEachLista' at the line before the if statement

Comment: Make it `template <typename T, typename F> void ForEachLista(T *lista, F func);` then you can pass a capturing lambda to it.